# How do miners construct and submit blocks

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory

1) Assume there are 20 nodes in network and all are receiving all transactions. Afterr 10 min they all pick transactions from their transaction pool and start creating a block. Now, will all nodes use the same transactions to create a block, or can each node have different transactions in that particular block?

2) If there are 20 nodes in network and all start creating blocks, what will happen if more then one node creates a block at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

> after 10 min all will pick transaction from their transaction pool and start creating block,

It doesn't work that way: All of the miners attempt to create a valid block (which is called mining) nonstop. On average, a valid block is found each 10 minutes.

When a transaction is broadcast, most of the miners will add it to their block template (if there's enough space left.). On the other hand, miners are allowed to choose their transactions, or keep the block empty, or fill the block with their useless free transactions. So, they can have different transactions in different orders.

> [Question 2]

The blocks will compete: The next block will choose one of them and that'd be the longest, valid chain. The other block will be *orphan*, or unaccepted by the network.